# How to do sliding window operations in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, sliding

I have a sequence data, transforming into RDD.

```
filteredRDD.collect()

[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9]
```

I like to get the delta the current one - the previous value, the output is 
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 4].

What kind of window function do we have spark 1.6?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to get your desired result is `zipWithIndex`

You can `zipWithIndex` your rdd (call it rdd1[Long, Int])
then

val `rdd2 = rdd1.map{case(index, value) => (index + 1, value)}`
Now if you val rdd3 = `rdd1.join(rdd2).mapValues(case (a, b) => a -b ).values`

that is your `row wise delta`. This is very efficient as it does not kick in a lot of shuffling.

Thanks
Manas